# JSON Structural Difference

Tags: python, json

I need to compare to JSON objects only for the keys, but not the value. These JSON objects can be nested ones, containing dictionaries, arrays, and other objects. Please suggest me an efficient way of doing this. Again, I need to compare only if both JSON objects have same keys and same structure.

Below are example JSONs

First JSON

```
{
    name: 'my object',
    description: 'it is an object',
    details: {
        it: 'has',
        an: 'array',
        with: ['a', 'few', 'elements']
    }
}
```

Second JSON

```
{
    name: 'updated object',
    description: 'it is an object!',
    details: {
        it: 'has',
        an: 'array',
        with: ['a', 'few', 'more', 'elements']
    }
}
```

Above pair of JSONs, when compared should not give any difference because they have the same keys.

Comment: Can you add the sample of code you are tried or json you want to do ?

Comment: What @VikasDamodar said is correct.Without the code and test data is difficult to sort out the problem....

Comment: hi all, sorry, added example JSONs now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, the example JSONs are not valid JSONs because keys in JSON has to be enclosed in `"`.

However, if you do have two valid JSON strings, you could parse them into a dictionary, then compare the structure of the dictionary using this function:

```
def equal_dict_structure(dict1, dict2):
    # If one of them, or neither are dictionaries, return False
    if type(dict1) is not dict or type(dict2) is not dict:
        return False

    dict1_keys = dict1.keys()
    dict2_keys = dict2.keys()

    if len(dict1_keys) != len(dict2_keys):
        # If they don't have the same amount of keys, they're not the same
        return False

    for key in dict1_keys:
        if key not in dict2_keys:
            return False

        dict1_value = dict1[key]
        dict2_value = dict2[key]

        if type(dict1_value) is dict:
            # If inner dictionary found, assert equality within inner dictionary
            if not equal_dict_structure(dict1_value, dict2_value):
                return False

    # No inequalities found
    return True
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer. Thanks